# Помогите решить задачу , нужно сделать через сканер , не понимаю как в метод вложить проверку ведённого значения в консоль

Tags: java

Помогите решить задачу , нужно сделать через сканер , не понимаю как в метод вложить проверку ведённого значения в консоль

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input your team: ");
        String team1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Input 1 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player1team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 2 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player2team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 3 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player3team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 4 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player4team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 5 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player5team1 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input your team: ");
        String team2 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Input 1 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player1team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 2 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player2team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 3 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player3team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 4 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player4team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input 5 player frags: ");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int player5team2 = scanner.nextInt();

        int avgResultTeam1 = (player1team1 + player2team1 + player3team1 + player4team1 + player5team1) / 5;

        int avgResultTeam2 = (player1team2 + player2team2 + player3team2 + player4team2 + player5team2) / 5;

        if (avgResultTeam1 > avgResultTeam2) {
            System.out.println("Победила команда " + team1 + " набравшая " + avgResultTeam1 + " очков");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Победила команда " + team2 + " набравшая " + avgResultTeam2 + " очков");
        }

        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите проверить после ввода значений? Вы знаете как работает scanner.hasNext()?

Comment: чтобы если ведённы буквы вместо цифр остановило код (Код это неудачная версия этот) и это записать в метод и  использовать этот кусок кода

Comment: if (scanner.nextLine()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }  Я не понимамю как эту строчку сделать методом

Comment: и как сделать чтобы если пользователь вводить буквы вместо цифр в консоль оно выбивало ему ошибку

Comment: Написал ниже ответ. если пользователь введет буквы вместо числа, при работе метода nextInt() , то получит в консоль исключение InputMismatchException. И программа завершит работу. Если вам важно проверять это условие. То вам нужен метод nextLine() и потом уже проверять полученную строку. - цифры в ней или буквы. В данном варианте до строки int player1team2 = scanner.nextInt(); ваша программа не доходит

Comment: у меня выходит так что теперь когда  я ввожу цифры на месте цифр мне тоже кидает ошибку:)

Comment: в двух словах я хочу чтобы там где были цифры будут цифры , а если вместо них будет буква выдаст ошибку, и это всё поместить в метод чтобоы не писать кучу кода, просто не могу разобратся как это сделать

Comment: вы не доходите в программе до места, где нужно вводить цифры (int player1team1 = scanner.nextInt();) .   вы цифры вводите на команде  if (scanner.hasNext()) . Который, естественно возвращает true вне зависимости что вы ввели. И вы попадаете на команду завершения программы

Comment: так я и не пойму как это должно выглядеть

Comment: Переписал код, посмотрите ниже в ответах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашей программе вы в любом случае попадаете на строку  System.exit(0); и программа завершает свою работу. Какой принцип работы метода scanner.hasNext(): данный метод возвращает true пока не закончится поток. При чтении из файла - концом потока будет конец файла. При чтении с клавиатуры концом потока будет ввод ^D (в Windows CTRL+D). То есть вы доходите до строки

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
```

В ЛЮБОМ случае попадаете в эту ветку и на команде System.exit(0); завершаете программу.
Вам нужно убрать эту проверку, потом считывать данные с помощью метода  scanner.nextLine() а не nextInt(). И проверять этот nextLine(): цифры там или нет. Вашу проверки с hasNext() удалите все, потому что вы будете в любом случае в них попадать и программа будет завершаться. Попробуйте переписать код без них, если не получится - напишите

Добавил мой вариант исправленного кода:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input your team: ");
        String team1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Input 1 player frags: ");
        int player1team1=0;
        try {
             player1team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}

        System.out.println("Input 2 player frags: ");
        int player2team1=0;
        try {
            player2team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}

        int player3team1=0;
        try {
            player3team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}

        System.out.println("Input 4 player frags: ");
        int player4team1=0;
        try {
            player4team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}
        System.out.println("Input 5 player frags: ");
        int player5team1=0;
        try {
            player5team1 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}

        System.out.print("Input your team: ");
        String team2 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Input 1 player frags: ");
        int player1team2=0;
        try {
            player1team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}
        System.out.println("Input 2 player frags: ");
        int player2team2=0;
        try {
            player2team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}
        System.out.println("Input 3 player frags: ");
        int player3team2=0;
        try {
            player3team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}
        System.out.println("Input 4 player frags: ");
        int player4team2=0;
        try {
            player4team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}
        System.out.println("Input 5 player frags: ");
        int player5team2=0;
        try {
            player5team2 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException exc) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");}

        int avgResultTeam1 = (player1team1 + player2team1 + player3team1 + player4team1 + player5team1) / 5;

        int avgResultTeam2 = (player1team2 + player2team2 + player3team2 + player4team2 + player5team2) / 5;

        if (avgResultTeam1 > avgResultTeam2) {
            System.out.println("Победила команда " + team1 + " набравшая " + avgResultTeam1 + " очков");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Победила команда " + team2 + " набравшая " + avgResultTeam2 + " очков");
        }

        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Вариант с методом:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input your team: ");
        String team1 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Input 1 player frags: ");
        int player1team1 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 2 player frags: ");
        int player2team1 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 3 player frags: ");
        int player3team1 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 4 player frags: ");
        int player4team1 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 5 player frags: ");
        int player5team1 = getValue();
        System.out.print("Input your team: ");
        String team2 = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Input 1 player frags: ");
        int player1team2 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 2 player frags: ");
        int player2team2 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 3 player frags: ");
        int player3team2 =  getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 4 player frags: ");
        int player4team2 = getValue();
        System.out.println("Input 5 player frags: ");
        int player5team2 = getValue();

        int avgResultTeam1 = (player1team1 + player2team1 + player3team1 + player4team1 + player5team1) / 5;

        int avgResultTeam2 = (player1team2 + player2team2 + player3team2 + player4team2 + player5team2) / 5;

        if (avgResultTeam1 > avgResultTeam2) {
            System.out.println("Победила команда " + team1 + " набравшая " + avgResultTeam1 + " очков");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Победила команда " + team2 + " набравшая " + avgResultTeam2 + " очков");
        }

        scanner.close();

    }

    public static int getValue(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int value=scanner.nextInt();

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: я такую структуру ещё не выучил, а как через nextLine?  :)))))

Comment: Можно убрать тогда try - catch блоки и просто считывать цифры командой player1team1 = scanner.nextInt();     Только при этом при вводе букв вместо цифр - у вас программа будет завершаться с ошибкой, оно же исключение InputMismatchException

Comment: а как метод сделать чтобы  не повторялись if из этого? чтобы не прописывать каждый раз if?

Comment: if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value! ");
            System.exit(0);
        }

Comment: как сделать из этого метод?

Comment: А сейчас перепишу

Comment: if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        }else{ 
            System.out.println("You put the wrong value");
            System.exit(0);
        }

Comment: Вот так это должно выглядеть , я понял, метод из этого сделать получается не докумекаю как

Comment: Добавил вариант с методом

Comment: а как чтобы оно в методе выводило что вы не то ввели когда буква попадает?

Comment: if(scanner.hasNextInt()){ }else{ System.out.println("You put the wrong value"); System.exit(0); }  или  мне обязательно это каждый раз прописывать под каждой переменной?

Comment: Либо try-catch и обрабатывать исключение, либо считывать строку и потом проверять ее с помощью регулярного выражения. Других способов в голову не приходит.

Comment: спасибо огромное , кое как разобрался ))